# Is it possible to retrieve the logged message as a string from boost::log::record_view?

Tags: boost-log

The [documentation of `record_view`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/record_view.html) states that it encapsulates the log message string.

I'd like to retrieve it in the context of the `consume` function of a custom `basic_string_backend` subclass.

Is it possible, or do I have to derive from `basic_formatted_sink_backend`?

Comment: I suppose you could always store a local copy the logged string in parallel somewhere else (which is what we do in our wrapper for boost.log)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it like this:

```
void consume(boost::logger::record_view const& rec)
{
    std::string myString = *rec[boost::logger::expressions::smessage];
    // etc...
}
```

Include boost/logger/expressions.h to get boost::logger::expressions::smessage.

Comment: Where the hell is all of this documented? I find Boost.Log incredibly complex and confusing, but their documentation isn't exactly helpful. I've seen no information in the docs on how to use the `record_view` object.

Comment: @void.pointer It's been too long, I have no idea where I found this initially :) It does show up in one of the examples under Log Record Formatting / Custom Formatting Functions: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/formatters.html#log.tutorial.formatters.custom_formatting_functions

Comment: I am going to give up on using it, I am trying to set it up and it is too difficult